# Is there some type of SPDT device that can carry high-current DC loads while closed, but switches when there is no current?

Tags: relay, high-current, latching-relay

In particular, I'm looking for a type of relay-like device that:

- Is mechanically latching (or similar)
- Is effectively SPDT
- Can handle 50+ Amps DC when closed
- Is extremely safe and reliable
- Will fit in the palm of my hand

I'm assuming the best way to achieve this would be to find a relay that can handle high currents while closed, but can't handle switching under high currents. This would be perfect, as I plan to switch these relays only when the system in question has almost no current running through it, so a low current rating should be fine - however, I also want to be 100% sure that the relays can handle much larger currents that will be run through them after they have closed one way or the other, and ensure there will be no arcing across the relay or failures due to hard jolts.

Does such a thing exist? Or are relays the wrong way to go about this? Would I need to look at custom-designing something?

Obviously, I'm not seeking any specific product recommendations, but I've not really found any good way to look for anything that meets these criteria and was hoping somebody might be able to point me at a type or category of relays that I can use to narrow my own search, or maybe some non-relay device that might do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Someone before had recommended looking at Smart Meter Relays, but those seem to be focused on AC applications (which makes sense).

In short, I have no idea if this kind of thing even exists, and would certainly love if there is some kind of title or keywords I could use to do my own further research.

Comment: It's not even clear to me what you really want. Are you saying that you want the relay to be ***unable*** to switch, when high currents are active through the SPDT switch, but will permit switching when these came currents through the SPDT switch are sufficiently "low?"

Comment: _"Obviously, I'm not seeking any specific product recommendations"_ - Yes, you are. Latching relays exist, and most can pass more current than they can switch reliably. So you are looking for a relay with specific specifications. Maybe what you want doesn't exist - if so that's because you are not looking for the right specs or they are unreasonable. I googled "latching relay 50A" and this was on the first page:- https://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/eu/50a-latching-relay-for-building-automation-iot-switching-actuators.htm

Comment: "_Latching relays exist, and most can pass more current than they can switch reliably._"

Would that info normally be found on a spec sheet? I've found most spec sheets I've been looking at to not include any graphs that show that, but maybe I've been looking for the wrong thing?

Thanks!